# MVVM Light EventToCommand for a clickevent in custom grid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I've been trying to get MVVM Lights EventToCommand to work. Ive looked at every sample i could find, even downloaded a sample app from the authors site but no luck.

Im using MVVM Light because i need the eventargs passed to my command.

Im using a custom grid that inherits from the standard wpf Grid.

XAML:

```
<cc:MapGrid x:Name="grdTopLayer" Height="448" Width="640" Background="White">
      <i:Interaction.Triggers>
           <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftButtonDown">
                <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding GridClickCommand}" PassEventArgsToCommand="True" />
           </i:EventTrigger>
      </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</cc:MapGrid>
```

DataContext is set to my viewmodel for the window.

ViewModel:

```
public RelayCommand<MouseEventArgs> GridClickCommand { get; private set; }

 private void InitializeCommands()
    {
        GridClickCommand = new RelayCommand<MouseEventArgs>(param => _gridHelper.AddGridImageToGrid(param), can => true);
    }
```

Initialize commands is called in viewmodel constructor.

What am i missing here?

Add_OnStartup:

```
private void App_OnStartup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        var mainWindow = new MainWindow
        {
                DataContext = new MainViewModel(new XmlReader(), new XmlWriter(), new GridHelper())
        };

        mainWindow.Show();
    }
```

Comment: probably cc:MapGrid DataContext is not set properly.

Comment: is set it in App_Startup like so

Comment: see how i set datacontext in my edit

Comment: try in binding <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding DataContext.GridClickCommand}" PassEventArgsToCommand="True" /> and open output window in visual studio while debugging and check are there any errors in bindings listed.

Comment: Thanks for the Output window tip. Was totally unrelated to the command. Got a null reference exception i only saw in output that i had to set to Throw in Debug -> Exceptions. Thanks!